# Hello, I am trying to lock the cells in an excel sheet based on the values in other sheet of the excel

Tags: excel, vba, locking, cells

I have tried various codes that seem to work perfectly for others but not in my case. Before i write any code the sheet, all the cells in my sheet appear as Locked anyways. I am stuck here and do not know what can be done here.

I tried this code but nothing seems to be locked,i can still do whatever i want in the sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("A1") = "Accepting" Then
        Range("B1:B4").Locked = False
    ElseIf Range("A1") = "Refusing" Then
        Range("B1:B4").Locked = True
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Just a small hint - record a macro, on which you lock the worksheet and see the generated code.

Answer (score 0):

Locking a range will have no effect unless the sheet is also protected.

For instance `Range("B1:B4").Locked = True` won't work until you do `YourWorksheet.Protect`. You can unprotect it after by doing `YourWorksheet.Unprotect`.

Comment: Can you please incorporate the change you ask in the code i have provided above and i can see how that works